# Least Square and Gram-Schmidt - inconsistency in Introduction to Linear Algebra 4th edition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, least-squares

In his book "Introduction to Linear Algebra" (4th edition), Pr. Strang explains in chapter 4.2 (p. 210) that the best approximation of a vector $x$ when 
$$Ax=b$$

has no solution is $\hat x$ and is found by this formula:

$$A^TA\hat x=A^Tb$$

Assuming the columns of $A$ spans a subspace.

Later on, in chapter 4.4 (p. 233), introducing the Gram-Schmidt process, he explains that the orthogonal matrix $Q$ which columns are orthonormal and spans the same subspace as $A$ can reduce the equation to:

$$\hat x=Q^Tb$$

because $Q^TQ=I$. However, a little later p. 236, after explaining the $QR$ factorization, Pr Strang explains that as $A=QR$ then, $\hat x$ can be found by:
$$\hat x=R^{-1}Q^Tb$$

Is it the same $\hat x$. If yes, why multiplying by $R^{-1}$ produces the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right and the equation should be

$$R\hat x=Q^Tb$$

Here's a quick example to show they are not the same thing

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Then use Gram-Schmidt and normalize to get

$Q=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt{3} & 0 \\ 1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{3} & -1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$

You can find $R=Q^TA=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{3} & 2\sqrt{3} \\ 0 &\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Consider $b=\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\0\end{bmatrix}$. $Ax=b$ is not consistent.

Note $Q^Tb=\begin{bmatrix}7/\sqrt{3}\\4/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Now hold on that and compute $A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 6 \\
6 & 14\end{bmatrix}$

And $A^Tb=\begin{bmatrix}7 \\ 18 \end{bmatrix}$

$A^TA$ is invertible with $(A^TA)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}7/3 & -1 \\
-1 & 1/2\end{bmatrix}$

Multiply out $(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb=\begin{bmatrix}-5/3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\neq \begin{bmatrix}7/\sqrt{3}\\4/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}=Q^Tb$

Note though if you compute $R^{-1}$ and multiply $R^{-1}Q^Tb=\begin{bmatrix}-5/3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Alternatively the author could have said the following
$$Q^TA\hat x=Q^Tb$$

Comment: However, the initial reasoning is still valid. If Q represents the same subspace as A, then $Q^TQ\hat x=Q^Tb$ and $Q^TQ=I$ by definition, then, $\hat x=Q^Tb$.

Comment: When the author says "the equation" is he referring to $Ax=b$ or $Qx=b$ ?

Comment: $A^TA\hat x=A^Tb$. You substistute A by Q and you get $\hat x=Q^Tb$

Comment: It shouldn't be substituting in Q for A it's using the QR-factorization of A. $A=QR$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $R$ is invertible

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition

Comment: Okay I've edited to add an example to help you see they're not the same